# How to add padding to an UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

The text inside an UILabel is smashed against the left and right borders. Is there an way of adding some inner padding to the UILabel, so that text won't touch the inner borders so closely?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just adjust the position of the label (I'm not aware of any other method, although someone else might).  If you have an issue with background colors (for instance), make the background a separate `UIView` and put the label on top of it.